# How to have the units for energy show as kW h instead of h kW?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, units

I observe the following in Wolfram Language:

```
Quantity[ 1, "Kilowatt hours" ] (* or "Kilowatts" * "Hours" *)

(* 1 h kW *)
```

That looks rather unconventional and in Wolfram Alpha it is done as `kW h`, for example: [kW vs. kWh](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kW+vs.+kWh)

How can this be achieved in Mathematica being compatible to the units framework?

EDIT:

Some more peculiarities.

```
Quantity[ 1, "Megawatt hours" ]
(* 1 h MW *)

(* but *)

Quantity[ 1, "USDollars" / "Megawatt hours" ]
(* Quantity: Unable to interpret unit specification *)
```

It is not the age of energy as of yet. ;-)

Comment: it seems to be baked into the display by frontend. Compare `Quantity[1, "Hours"*"Kilowatts"]` and `Quantity[1, "Kilowatts"*"Hours"]`  they both give `1 h kW`  May be it uses some internal ordering based on letters or something like that?

Comment: I do not think there is a way to change that. One can try to use [$PrePrint](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html) to change the display, but it is tricky for this kind of output.  Better learn to live with it :)  You could submit request to WRI to change this and see what they say?

Comment: `Quantity[1, "USDollars"/("Kilowatts"*"Hours")]` seems to solve your dollar issue. FYI, it seems to be sorting alphabetically by the unit name.

Comment: @gwr It is a `new kind of units` :)

Comment: If you are really desperate you could do 
`Unprotect[RowBox]; 
RowBox[{"\"h\"", "\[ThinSpace]", "\"kW\""}] := RowBox[{"kWh"}]`.
But that is maybe not the right way to eat cookies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
QuantityUnits`Private`getCompoundUnitBoxes@Quantity[_, "Hours" "Kilowatts"] := 
 RowBox[{"\"kW\"", "\[ThinSpace]", "\"h\""}]

QuantityUnits`Private`getCompoundUnitBoxes@Quantity[_, _/("Hours" "Kilowatts")] :=
 RowBox[{"\"per\"", "\"kW\"", "\[ThinSpace]", "\"h\""}]
```

[image]

---

### Update for Version 14 or Earlier

At least since version 14, the design of `Quantity` seems to be changed. Now we need the following code instead:

```
QuantityUnits`Private`getCompoundUnitBoxes["Hours" "Kilowatts"] := 
 RowBox[{"\"kW\"", "\[ThinSpace]", "\"h\""}]

QuantityUnits`Private`ToNDBoxes[{}, {"Hours", "Kilowatts"}] := 
 RowBox[{"\"per\"", "\"kW\"", "\[ThinSpace]", "\"h\""}]
```

Comment: It seems that this is not working anymore as of `v14`?

Comment: @gwr Luckily it's not too hard to fix. See my update :) .